# Unmarshal TOML in Go With Profile Section

Tags: go, unmarshalling, toml, viper-go

I am currently trying to unmarshal a config file (super similar to the config file that AWS uses when using their CLI). However, nothing is getting added to the struct I created.

Here is my source code:

```
func main() {
    config, _ := GetConfig(".")
    fmt.Println(config) <--- Prints "{map[]}"

}

type Configuration struct {
    Id     int64 `toml:"id"`
    Key    int64 `toml:"key"`
}

type Configurations struct {
    Config map[string]Configuration
}

func GetConfig(path string) (configurations Configurations, err error) {
    viper.AddConfigPath(path)
    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.SetConfigType("toml")

    err = viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("No config file found!")
        return configurations, err
    }

    err = viper.Unmarshal(&configurations)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("No config user found!")
    }
    return configurations, err
}
```

And here is what is in my *config.toml* file:

```
[profile]
id  = 123 
key = 456
```

Comment: can you try with `type Configurations map[string]Configuration ` ?

Comment: For any viewers interested, I decided to work with a JSON config file rather than TOML. This allowed me to retrieve/write data to/from a Go struct super easily using Viper.